# VMware ESXi 6 Free License

Tags: esxi, vmware-server, esx

I came to know that VMware ESXi 6 are providing free license with some limited features. I also explored it. Those features are sufficient for our organisation. I am little bit confused whether it can be used in our organisation or not!!! 
Can anyone of you please confirm me whether we can use VMware ESXi 6 free version in our organisation without any license issue?

Thanks,
Sourav Maity

Answer (score 0):

This question is hard to answer unless we really know what your organization is doing. Generally you can use the free license with the noted limitations (see link 1) and commercial use is fine. However, there is a limitation on commercializing the VMs as product, potentially including the offering of root VM servers (see link 2, especially post 7).

The links:

1. https://serverfault.com/questions/736162/understanding-the-vmware-esxi-limitations-of-the-free-version
2. https://communities.vmware.com/message/1141021#1141021

Please note that I am not a lawyer and therefore my answer should be taken as interpretation of the license information available to me at this point in time.